# Is this a mistake of the core python programming,2nd editon?

Tags: python

In a section, the author writes two sentences showing self-contradiction .

the first one:

```
A shallow copy of an object is defined to be a newly created object of the same 
type as the original object whose contents are references to the elements in the 
original object.
```

the second one:

```
when shallow copies are made, the string is explicitly copied and a new (string) 
object created
```

First sentence means string objects and list objects are all references (not explicitly copied)when shallow copied.

Second sentence means string objects are explicitly copied when shallow copied.

I think first sentence is right. I think the second one should be:

```
when "wifey[0] = 'jane'" is executed, the string is explicitly copied and a new 
(string) object created
```

I don't konw why the author wrote the second one. Am I right?

this is the whole material:

**6.20. *Copying Python Objects and Shallow and Deep Copies**

Earlier in Section 3.5, we described how object assignments are simply object references. This means that when you create an object, then assign that object to another variable, Python does not copy the object. Instead, it copies only a reference to the object.

For example, let us say that you want to create a generic profile for a young couple; call it person. Then you copy this object for both of them. In the example below, we show two ways of copying an object, one uses slices and the other a factory function. To show we have three unrelated objects, we use the id() built-in function to show you each object's identity. (We can also use the is operator to do the same thing.)

```
>>> person = ['name', ['savings', 100.00]]
>>> hubby = person[:]       # slice copy
>>> wifey = list(person)    # fac func copy
>>> [id(x) for x in person, hubby, wifey]
[11826320, 12223552, 11850936]
```

Individual savings accounts are created for them with initial $100 deposits. The names are changed to customize each person's object. But when the husband withdraws $50.00, his actions affected his wife's account even though separate copies were made. (Of course, this is assuming that we want them to have separate accounts and not a single, joint account.) Why is that?

```
>>> hubby[0] = 'joe'
>>> wifey[0] = 'jane'
>>> hubby, wifey
(['joe', ['savings', 100.0]], ['jane', ['savings', 100.0]])
>>> hubby[1][1] = 50.00
>>> hubby, wifey
(['joe', ['savings', 50.0]], ['jane', ['savings', 50.0]])
```

The reason is that we have only made a shallow copy. **A shallow copy of an object is defined to be a newly created object of the same type as the original object whose contents are references to the elements in the original object.** In other words, the copied object itself is new, but the contents are not. Shallow copies of sequence objects are the default type of copy and can be made in any number of ways: (1) taking a complete slice [:], (2) using a factory function, e.g., list(), dict(), etc., or (3) using the copy() function of the copy module.

Your next question should be: When the wife's name is assigned, how come it did not affect the husband's name? Shouldn't they both have the name 'jane' now? The reason why it worked and we don't have duplicate names is because of the two objects in each of their lists, the first is immutable (a string) and the second is mutable (a list). Because of this, **when shallow copies are made, the string is explicitly copied and a new (string) object created** while the list only has its reference copied, not its members. So changing the names is not an issue but altering any part of their banking information is. Here, let us take a look at the object IDs for the elements of each list. Note that the banking object is exactly the same and the reason why changes to one affects the other. Note how, after we change their names, that the new name strings replace the original 'name' string:

BEFORE:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in hubby]
[9919616, 11826320]
>>> [id(x) for x in wifey]
[9919616, 11826320]
```

AFTER:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in hubby]
[12092832, 11826320]
>>> [id(x) for x in wifey]
[12191712, 11826320]
```

Comment: I think the author referred to immutable types, but it does sound confusing and incorrect to say a new copy of the string is assigned. It is for string literals, not for already existing string objects. Things are muddled more by string interning (use strings with spaces in them to avoid the effects of interning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your next question should be: When the wife's name is assigned, how
>   come it did not affect the husband's name? Shouldn't they both have
>   the name 'jane' now? The reason why it worked and we don't have
>   duplicate names is because of the two objects in each of their lists,
>   the first is immutable (a string) and the second is mutable (a list).

This explanation is incorrect, although the facts cited are true. In fact, the reason why it worked and we don't have duplicate names is that the line `wifey[0] = 'jane'` assigned a new value to an element of `wifey`, which is a different list from `hubby`. By contrast, the line `hubby[1][1] = 50.0` did not assign a new value to an element of `hubby`. Rather, it assigned a new value to an element of `hubby[1]`, which as previously discussed is the same object as `wifey[1]`.

The fact that `hubby[0]` and `wifey[0]` happen to be immutable values is true but irrelevant.

You can prove this as follows:

```
person = [[], ['savings', 100.00]]
hubby = list(person)
wifey = list(person)
```

So, both elements are mutable because both are lists.

```
hubby[0] = [1,2,3]
id(hubby[0])
id(wifey[0])
```

Behold, now the first elements refer to different lists!

> Because of this, when shallow copies are made, the string is
>   explicitly copied and a new (string) object created while the list
>   only has its reference copied, not its members.

I can't think of any way to construe this as true. If you make a shallow copy of something that contains a string, then that string is not copied. The situation is exactly the same for lists, if you make a shallow copy of something containing a list then that list is not copied.

If you make a copy of a string itself, then the string *still* need not actually be copied (since it's immutable). As an optimization you could just be given back the same object again, and for most purposes that's just as good. Indeed, Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.2.5 (which are what I have installed here) both make that optimization on all three of `original[:]`, `str(original)` and `copy.copy(original)`.

If for some obscure reason you actually want two equal strings that are not identical (perhaps to test the performance of `==` or something, I don't know), then you basically have to try to trick the Python runtime: `(original + ' ')[0:-1]` or whatever.